# Vector basemap sources for QGIS

Tags: qgis

Any known sources of Vector Basemaps for QGIS, excluding "OpenMapTiles.com" that preset upon the installation of the plugin "Vector Tiles Reader Plugin"?

Really looking for a hillshade vector map and a contour line vector map that I can add to QGIS.

Comment: It depends if the Vector Basemap is compliant to the Vector Tiles Reader QGIS Plugin https://github.com/geometalab/Vector-Tiles-Reader-QGIS-Plugin/issues/112

Comment: Vector Tiles (ZoomStack Ordnance Survey GB) https://medium.com/@tomchadwin/os-zoomstack-first-impressions-4b2a1120cb80

Comment: How can a hillshade be a vector?

Comment: @csk with styling - https://blog.mapbox.com/designing-a-vector-terrain-map-for-outdoor-apps-3fbcec0d5864

Comment: Apparently a hillshade *can* be a vector. Thank you @user2856, I learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question: QGIS since 3.12 supports natively the vector tile parsing, rendering and styling - implementing the "Vector Tiles" as layer, so the mentioned Vector Tiles Reader QGIS plugin is not required.

If you are looking for hillshade and countour vector maps to add into QGIS easily - I recommend checking the "Outdoor style" mentioned in:

https://www.maptiler.com/news/2021/09/vector-basemaps-in-qgis/

This means to do:

1. Open QGIS (3.12+)
2. Click on the menu Plugins → Manage and Install Plugins…
3. Search for maptiler
4. Click on the Install Plugin (Reinstall, if you already have the old version installed)
5. Restart QGIS
6. Double click in Browser on the left on MapTiler -> Outdoor

This map is fully editable - adjust the visual, add your own layers and print or export in vector format at selected DPI.